# Is it possible to define a macro: anything else to dispatch on functions?

Tags: clojure, static-methods

I don't know how to really name my problem since I do not know how to even start thinking about this so I will state the problem.
Imagine I have several static methods of a Java object which use the same syntax, for instance:

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/blob/master/nd4j-backends/nd4j-api-parent/nd4j-api/src/main/java/org/nd4j/linalg/ops/transforms/Transforms.java

```
/**
 * Floor function
 *
 * @param ndArray
 * @return
 */
public static INDArray floor(INDArray ndArray, boolean dup) {
    return exec(dup ? new Floor(ndArray.dup()) : new Floor(ndArray));

}

/**
 * Signum function of this ndarray
 *
 * @param toSign
 * @return
 */
public static INDArray sign(INDArray toSign, boolean dup) {
    return exec(dup ? new Sign(toSign, toSign.dup()) : new Sign(toSign));
}
```

So here is a sample dummy wrapper:

```
(defn floor
 ^INDArray
  [^INDArray a ^boolean dup]
  (Transforms/floor a dup))

(defn sign
 ^INDArray
  [^INDArray a ^boolean dup]
  (Transforms/sign a dup))
```

The problem here is that you waste time to write functions with identical templates which is OK for the first time... but imagine you want to update ALL of them in case of a change/broken code/performance tuning/whatever.
I searched the problem but found nothing about it. The ideal case would be (a macro?) like:

```
(defoperator floor Transforms/floor)
```

Or

```
(def floor (->operator Transforms/floor))
```

I don't know if it is possible to call a "generic" static method for starters even if it is a quite common use case and did not find any answer.
I suspect it is not the case since typing "Transforms/floor" in repl treats it as a static field and not method but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a macro that expands to a function definition containing the duplicate code:

```
(defmacro defoperator [op]
  `(defn ~op ; Create a function with "op" as the name
     ^INDArray
     [^INDArray a#, dup#]
     (. Transforms ~op a# dup#))) ; (. Transforms floor) is the same as (Transforms/floor)
```

Calling `(defoperator floor)` now emits a function definition that looks like:

```
(defn floor
  ^INDArray
  [^INDArray a, dup]
  (. Transforms floor a dup))
```

This macro assumes that the static method name is the same as the function that you want emitted. If you want them to potentially differ, you can use an alternate version:

```
(defmacro defoperator [fn-name static-name]
  `(defn ~fn-name
     ^INDArray
     [^INDArray a#, dup#]
     (. Transforms ~static-name a# dup#)))
```

---

Note, I got rid of your `^boolean` hint. You can't hint Boolean primitives. I'm not sure what version of Clojure you're using, but that doesn't work in 1.8.0.